# How to get initial data from api before app loaded in next.js

Tags: next.js

I want to load some data from api before application rendered.

Yes, I know we can do it in getInitialProps method of component, but I don't want load it on each component loading,
I need make only 1 api call and make accessible retrieved data among all components. What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: You might be able do that in the `getInitialProps` of the `_app`.js file.
([nextjs doc][1])


  [1]: https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-app

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, I know we can do it in getInitialProps method of component

I think this may be where your confusion is coming from. The getInitialProps method is for *page* loads. Not for individual *component* loads.

> I need make only 1 api call and make accessible retrieved data among all components.

There are a couple of ways to do this.

**If you want to take advantage of SSR**

Use getInitalProps *for the page load* and [then pass the props down into sub components as you would in normal react application](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

**If you just want to stick to React**

Make a higher level component that contains all of the sub components that need the api data. Call the api in the [ComponentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) method or you could use [React  Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).  From the higher level component again pass the data via props as you would in a normal react application.

Either way you are limiting the number of times you make the api call. That way you aren't hitting the endpoint each time the DOM re-renders each and every component.

Both the [Next.js Learn](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started) and [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) are excellent - I'm there all the time!